# Visual Studio 2008 - How to keep Error List Window always open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Every time I open Visual Studio 2008, I have to go to View, Error List to open the Error List Window and VS2008 doesn't save the setting for the next time I start it. Also, after I exit debug mode on the app I am coding, the Error List Window on the bottom of the page disappears!

How do I have VS2008 save the setting to display the error window on startup and always stay up no matter what?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is

- "pin" the Error List window in place by pressing the thumbnail icon in the top right corner of the window.
- Then, click on the down arrow, and de-select "Auto-Hide" from the drop down and it will remain open!

[image: Pinning the Error List window]

Comment: thanks for your response. I also had to click on the down arrow, and de-select "Auto-Hide" from the drop down and it will remain open!

Comment: @Brian McCarthy You're welcome - I just confirmed that de-selecting "auto-hide" from the drop down does the same as clicking the pin button on the window

Comment: I think the problem was that my Error List Window defaulted to Auto-Hide. Pinning it made it a tab on the bottom panel but after I clicked on the code section, it disappeared so I had to un-check the Auto-Hide option on there.